# input color background problema (safari)

Tags: css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el input es de color verde pero en el navegador safari lo detecta verde y con un color blanco,  este problema sucede precisamente usando un smartphone,

Usando el navegador Chrome esta bien correctamente el color, he buscado algún webkit que me diera la solución al problema pero no me da la solución.. alguna sugerencia para este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
               input#btn-submit{
               position: absolute;
               top: 142px;
               left: 82px;
               background-color:rgba(0, 156, 85,0.9);
               line-height: 30px;
               width: 100px;
               height: 40px;
               font-size: 19px;
               color: white;
               border: none;


          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con `linear-gradient`:

```css
button {
  background: rgb(91,255,57);
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(91,255,57,1) 0%, rgba(188,201,204,1) 100%);
  padding: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Login</button>
```

Puedes generar mas gradientes [en esta pagina (CSS Gradient - Generator)](https://cssgradient.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías generar la gradiente utilizando sólo el color verde y usando -moz-linear-gradient. Así:

```
input#btn-submit {
           position: absolute;
           top: 142px;
           left: 82px;
           background-color:rgba(0, 156, 85,0.9);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 156, 85,0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 
           156, 85,0.9) 50%, rgba(0, 156, 85,0.9);
           line-height: 30px;
           width: 100px;
           height: 40px;
           font-size: 19px;
           color: white;
           border: none;
      }
```